# Flutter: How to hide TextField text pointer (cursor) when use initial value text (Android)

Tags: flutter, textfield

Use case: Messaging app you edit your message: keyboard, blinking cursor and initial text appears but pointer (cursor) is not

But on Flutter when you use initial text (or via textController) there are always pointer(cursor) which is not wanted

Example

[image]
[image]

Steps to reproduce:
run `flutter create bug`

edit main.dart to replace center text (line 100) to  `MyStatefulPage(),`

```
class MyStatefulPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyStatefulPage> createState() {
    return _MyStatefulPageState();
  }
}
class _MyStatefulPageState extends State<MyStatefulPage> {

  TextEditingController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = new TextEditingController();
    controller.text = 'My Initial Text';
  } 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
       border: InputBorder.none
      ),
      // showCursor: false,
      controller: controller,
      autofocus: true,
      maxLines: 8,
    );
  }
}
```

With that code when you open app keyboard will appear but so will pointer(cursor) I want to hide this cursor(pointer).

**Note**: it's only for Android.

Comment: Hi, @philip did you resolve your issue?

Comment: Hi @DMDev No, this question was created almost 2 years ago. Maybe some of the answers are correct but I haven't tested them if you will find a solution please post it here as well, Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

TextField set enableInteractiveSelection property to false can resolve this issue

Comment: Still, the pointer is visible below the cursor

Answer (score 5):

To hide the **blinking cursor**

[image]

Add this line of code

```
showCursor: false
```

To hide the **editing pointer**

[image]

Add this line of code

```
enableInteractiveSelection: false
```

Answer (score 3):

in textformfield use showCursor: false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

TextFormField cursorHeight: 0 and cursorWidth: 0 can hide the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

TextFormField(enableInteractiveSelection: false)

Answer (score 0):

readOnly: true,
hide the cursor

Answer (score 0):

You may need to disable TextField. See the example below to disable TextField input in Flutter.

```
 TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Your Name (Disabled)",
                  enabled: false //disabel this text field input
              )
          ),
```